# giving multiple users access to one alias

Tags: exchange-2010

My company has an alias (an email) sponsorship@XXXXX.com. One of my managers is currently owner of the alias, but wants himself, and a team of 4 other people to be able to access all the emails sent to this email. How would I do this?

I thought of setting up a new mailbox called "sponsorship", setting the old sponsorship@XXXXX.com alias to this new mailbox and then giving all the users access to that mailbox, would this be an inappropriate solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just set up a Distribution Group with that email address and add the appropriate users to the DG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a Shared Mailbox for sponsorship@... and give access to the appropriate people.  If will even automatically show up in outlook if you set it up right.

I believe you need to use powershell to create a shared mailbox.

Open Exchange Management Shell.  For a mailbox called "Shared mailbox" with the email address "shared@xyz.com", and give permission to the user grant, you would run:

`New-Mailbox -Name "Shared Mailbox" -Alias shared -Shared`

`Add-MailboxPermission "Shared Mailbox" -User grant -Accessrights FullAccess`

The permissions can also be edited from the graphical console once the mailbox is created.
By default, the shared mailbox will automatically be opened as an additional mailbox in outlook for users you share it with.  [This page at technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529943%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) explains how to disable that feature if you don't want it.

Comment: do you mean the Exchange Management Shell?

Comment: Yes, the management shell.  Updating answer with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It is better/easier it to set `sponsorship@XXXXX.com` forward to all the 4 mailboxes.

### Create Redirect Rule in OWA

1. Create account
2. Login OWA
3. Create New Inbox Rule as follow (Options -> Create an Inbox Rule...)

   Select `[Apply to all messages]` and `Redirect the message to...`, in the address book pop-up, either select the 4 mail boxes from existing contacts or type in directly in the `To->` box.

Comment: how do I set the mailbox to forward to 4 other mailboxes?

Comment: I update my answer for OWA instruction.